# How can I create an if statement using logic gates?

Tags: java, algorithm, binary, logic

I am currently working on a basic binary multiplier and we are limited to using logic gates (AND/OR/NAND/NOR/XOR). I am trying to make the statement listing below but cannot figure out how this would be made without an if.

(x represents the multiplicand and y the multiplier)

```
if ((y & 1) != 0) product = add(product,x);
```

Comment: What do you mean by using logic gates provided? is there a shift on y missing here?

Comment: You need to better explain the restrictions you're working under.  (There are ways to do it without "if", but a bit ridiculous.)

Comment: Sorry, I will rephrase that part of the question. It means using AND, OR, XOR, NAND, NOR.

Comment: If you have a N-bit word, build (N*2 - 1) N-Bit "adders", where one input to the "odd" adders is the M1 word ANDed with the corresponding M2 bit, and the "even" adders add together successive stages of the "odd" adders.  (But actually the "even" adders need to be variable width, up to N*2 - 1.)

Comment: In this case, this particular code is within a loop with everything else done, but I am trying to rephrase this particular chunk of code so that it doesn't rely on the if statement since that isn't allowed. This code is essentially just the part that uses the furthest right binary digit and checks if it is a 1 or a 0. If it is a 1, add the multiplicand to the product. If not, finish the loop.

Comment: (OK, I didn't think that through too well - it's been about 40 years since I last designed a hardware multiplier.  I'm thinking you don't need the "odd"/"even" adders, but just one set.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case,

```
product += x & (-(y & 1));
```

would work, where the bit-twiddling is equivalent to ANDing all of `x` with the ones bit of `y` and then adding.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `add` does what it''s name implies, how about

```
product = add(product,(y & 1) * x);
```